# grep search + next line

Tags: grep

With the `grep` command, I found the text I need as follows:

```
grep 'C02' ~/temp/log.txt
```

Now, wherever I find the desired string, I would like to print the line following the found string.

For example, let's say that the desired text is `abc`, and `abc` is found on line 12, I would like to print line 13 too.

Comment: `grep -A1 'abc' ~/temp/log.txt` for **1** line of context **A**fter the match - see the `Context Line Control` subsection of the manual (`man grep`)

Comment: gnu grep makes it easy; [posix does not specify](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) the -A flag

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! on SE, it's expected that you do some basic research before coming here for help. for example, a search for "grep show next line" returned an indirect answer in the first result and a direct answer in the second. what have you done to try to solve this problem already?

Comment: You should use `grep -F 'C02'` instead as it is faster. [`grep -F` matches fixed strings.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) such as 'C02'

Answer (score 62):

If you are using Linux system, you can try:

```
grep -A1 "C02" ~/temp/log.txt


OPTIONS
       -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.
       -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.
       -C NUM, --context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.
```

You can use awk also as:

```
awk '/C02/{print;getline;print}' ~/temp/log.txt
```

Comment: also, `sed -n '/C02/{N; p}' ~/temp/log.txt`

Comment: For anyone wondering, for example -A9 will add 9 rows so that there are 10 shown in the output, not just the 0th and the ninth row.